# gnmenu integration with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react js. I need to integrated [Google Nexeus like menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/) to my app. I'm not sure how to include the custom javascript files in my react webpack setup. I tried to include it in following way. But it is not working. When I check the network communication in firefox developer tools I can see that same html content is comming as the response to `GET gnmenu.js`, not the actual javascript content.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Application</title>
    <link href="static/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/lato/lato.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/opensans/opensans.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="static/raleway/raleway.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0">
  <script src="/static/gnmenu.js"></script>
  <div id="content" class="myApp"></div>
    <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Has anyone used `gnmenu` with react?